# php get all connected client sockets

Tags: php

I'm trying to listen for a client socket connection, so every user to have the info of the connected people in the server.There is no such a info about the php sockets, so i'm asking , any ideas ?

Comment: Is this for a http client or some other type of connection?

Comment: You want a who's online script. A quick google search revealed http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/who-is-online-widget-php-mysql-jquery/

Comment: I will go with the way of Benny, i don't need mysql .. read ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually an [official documentation for socket](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create-listen.php) in the php website. The point is you can create a class that resembles socket server and then use `socket_create_listen()` inside one of the member function as specified in the examples on the website:

```
public function socketListen(){
        while( !( $this->lister = @socket_create_listen($this->porta) ) ){
            echo 'Aguarde..';
            sleep($this->wait);
        }
    }
```

Just read on the documentation and you'll be good. Hope that helps.